# Looking for specific string in an exception message in Java

Tags: java, exception

I have a library with a method that throws an IOException. Something like,

```
package helpful.library;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;

public class HelpfulClass{

    public MyObject MyMethod(String a) throws IOException {
        //does some stuff
        return helpfulMethod(String a);
    }

    private MyObject helpfulMethod(String a, int b) throws IOException {
        //does some stuff that includes retrieving a status code x
        if (x != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            throw new IOException("blah blah code: " + x);
        } 
        //does stuff and returns a MyObject object
    }
```

I want to call MyMethod from another app, and I would like to check for a specific status code (*x* in helpfulMethod) that is not *HttpStatus.SC_OK*. In Java is it good practice to use the exception message and check if the string contains my status code? 
Are there other ways to do it?
A possible idea is to change MyObject to throw another exception but that has a ripple effect on other apps that are expecting an IOException only.

Comment: It is definitely not a good practice to check for strings. 
1) It is a lot slower than implementing custom exceptions.
2) You loose type information.

I'd recommend to throw a custom exception

Comment: Why don't you subclass `IOException`?

Comment: Thanks. Ah makes sense - just to confirm, I'd need to then check if the subclass is instanceof in my app, right?

Comment: @KTings no, the catch statement will do that for you: `catch (MyIOException e)`.